# Using definition of logs, solve $5\log_7(n)=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to solve $5\log_7(n)=10$. I arrived at $n=7^5$ while the solution in my textbook says it's $49$

My working:

$$5\log_7(n)=10$$
$$\log_7(n^5)=10$$
$$7^{10}=n^5$$
$$n=7^{10-5}$$
$$n=7^5$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at 49?

(Meta question, is there a way that I can add comments next to each line of my working to say what I was thinking? I tried using '#' next to each line but that buckled the markup)

Comment: How did you go from $7^{10}=n^5$ to $n=7^{10-5}$?  That is your error.  It is not true that $a^b=c^d\implies a=c^{d-b}$

Comment: Oh, OK thanks for telling me. My ine of thought was that if I take the 5th root of n to get n, then I would also want the 5th root of 7^10 which I assumed to be 7^{10-5}

Comment: Taking the fifth root is not equivalent to subtracting $5$ from the exponent, it is equivalent to dividing the exponent by $5$.  Also, be careful with that if you deal with things which are not positive reals.  Several of the identities you think you know don't work for negative numbers or complex numbers as the base.

Comment: Should be $7^{10/5}$.  Also, to add comments you can either make the equations in line with single '$' sign followed by text or within the math environment you can add \quad to add some space and \text{comment} to add a comment.

Comment: Another alternative for adding comments would be setting this up as an array, `\begin{array}{rlr}5\log_7(n)&=10&\text{start}\\\log_7(n^5)&=10&\text{moving coefficient inside}\\7^{10}&=n^5&\text{raising 7 to power of each side}\end{array}` for instance producing $\begin{array}{rlr}5\log_7(n)&=10&\text{start}\\\log_7(n^5)&=10&\text{moving coefficient inside}\\7^{10}&=n^5&\text{raising 7 to power of each side}\end{array}$.  This also helps line the equations up.

Comment: [See more MathJax tips here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the tips on markup! WIll start using these on future posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did wrong is $n=7^{10-5}$ does not follow from $7^{10}=n^5$.

To fix your calculation (as WA Don pointed out in a comment),
$$
7^2=(7^{10})^{1/5}=(n^5)^{1/5}=n
$$

Alternatively,

\begin{align}
5\log_7(n)&=10\\
\log_7(n)&=2&\textrm{(dividing by $5$)}\\
n&=7^2=49&\textrm{($\log_ax=y$ iff $x=a^y$)}
\end{align}

---

For your meta question:

```
\begin{align}
5\log_7(n)&=10\\
\log_7(n)&=2&\textrm{(dividing by $5$)}\\
n&=7^2=49&\textrm{($\log_ax=y$ iff $x=a^y$)}
\end{align}
```